# API limitations to resize an image

Tags: api, vb6

I have a view that displays images and I'm offering zoom in/out options. 
I'm using OleCreatePictureIndirect function (VB6) to create the new picture. In some cases (when the picture is big) I get an empty image.
Does anybody know what is the API limitation for image size?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[KB163878](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163878) mentions bitmap limit of 48MB where `total size = width * height * bytes_per_pixel`.

You can use DIB sections to stay in user space where the total size can be bigger (and eventually get paged to disk).